# Delete files older than xx days

Tags: powershell, filesystems, delete-file

I need to delete some files programmatically (preferably using Powershell) from a folder than are older than a given amount of days.

I've written a simple script that will do this, however the issue I'm having is that it seems to have trouble even starting to delete, due to the sheer amount of files in the folder.

I'm looking for a way to delete in batches probably. So it would maybe get the first 1000, delete, and then so on.

Right now, the folder probably has several hundred thousand files, and is practically impossible to traverse.

```
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Path,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$DaysToDelete
)

$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays($DaysToDelete)
$LogFile = "FileCleanupLog-$(Get-Date -f yyyyMMdd_HH_mm_ss).txt";

function Log-Message
{
   Param ([string]$logtext)
   Add-content $LogFile -value $logtext
}

If (-Not (Test-Path $Path))
{
    Write-Host "Invalid Path provided!" -ForegroundColor Red
    Exit
}

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit }

If ($files.Count -GT 1) {
    $files | % {$directory=$_.DirectoryName;(Log-Message "Deleting File $directory\$_");$_ } | Remove-Item -Force 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried piping get-childitem to SELECT, as in `get-childitem . | select -first 100`?  You need to post the script that you currently have.

Comment: _I've written a simple script that will do this_ Perhaps you should include what you have tried so far. Right now this reads like a gimmie the codez question. For the most part we are here to help fix or improve existing code. Even if you did it in "batches" you would still be doing it one at a time unless you used jobs or something. Are you looking for progress indication? What is the harm in letting it run and do its thing? If done often enough only  the first pass is going to suck. I recently made a task to do this but the first run removed 5 million files took hours. Runs fine now.

Comment: If your existing code has logic errors perhaps we can fix those and show where you maybe went wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I was on my phone - hard to post code... I have added the code now. I have left it running for an hour, and it hasn't even gotten into the if statement yet. I wanted to do it in batches, inside a while loop or something like that, so I can actually see some progress.

Comment: Have you considered robocopy for this? You could configure it to give you a report when you are done.

Comment: I wasn't aware that robocopy was used to delete files?

Comment: I'm not near a computer but if no one else answers with a robocopy solution I will later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looping over all of the files and storing the files that are marked for deletion in a list and then looping over each file in the list again just pipe each file to the next command as you find them.

So replace this:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit }

If ($files.Count -GT 1) {
    $files | % {$directory=$_.DirectoryName;(Log-Message "Deleting File $directory\$_");$_ } | Remove-Item -Force 
}
```

With something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Force `
| Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } `
| % {
    $directory=$_.DirectoryName
    (Log-Message "Deleting File $directory\$_")
    $_ } `
| Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: Not huge gains here but why bother with `$directory=$_.DirectoryName`... might as well just do `"Deleting File $($_.FullName)"`

Comment: @Matt You'll have to ask the OP why.  The content of the `ForEach` body is not really germane to the problem so I left it functionally equivalent.

Comment: This looks good actually. Not sure why I used the $DirectoryName, probably a late night :) The batching was just a thought to make it quicker, but I think this may work.

Answer (score 1):

To meet your criteria of deleting files in batches of 1000, use the following.  The `select -first 1000` will cause it to only delete 1000 files each time it goes through the while loop.

```
while($true){
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | select -first 1000
    If ($files.Count -GT 1) {
        $files | % {$directory=$_.DirectoryName;(Log-Message "Deleting File $directory\$_");$_ } | Remove-Item -Force 
    } else {
        exit 
    }
}
```

I don't know if this will be faster--it depends on if PowerShell is smart enough to stop get-childitem after it finds the first 1000 files or not.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I'm not sure if batching will make things faster. In my experience, it does, but that's more from a SQL/.NET point of view.

Comment: It does look like `select` will short circuit the previous commands in the pipeline as of 3.0 [(documentation)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx): *"Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, Select-Object includes an optimization feature that prevents commands from creating and processing objects that are not used."* One issue here, though, is that within each loop the `Get-ChildItem` command is going to iterate over all of the files that were not deleted during each of the previous loops.

Comment: Instead of a crude `$true`/`exit` condition you could easily use you `$files.Count -GT 1` logic as the exit condition of the loop. `do{#stuff}while($files.Count -gt 1)`

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit that I am slightly mistaken with how I wanted [robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx) to work. While it can delete files, when told, it still has to perform a copy operation. So this suggestion is best run on the target machine and not using UNC paths. Disappointment aside I still think this is a viable solution. The main thing here is that robocopy will select only the files we need to without any post processing.

```
$sourceDirectory = "D:\temp\New folder"
$dummyDirectory = "D:\temp\trashbin"
$loggingFile = "D:\temp\FileCleanupLog-$(Get-Date -f yyyyMMdd_HH_mm_ss).txt"

# Build the dummy directory. It will be deleted in the end.
New-Item -Path $dummyDirectory -ItemType Directory | Out-Null

& robocopy.exe $sourceDirectory /njh /ndl /nc /njs /minage:$days /mov /e /ns /np /l | Set-Content $loggingFile

# Purge the dummy directory with all the content we don't want
Remove-Item -Path $dummyDirectory -Force -Confirm:$false -Recurse
```

Here is what all the switches used represent. Most are to clean up the output for logging. The log should just have a list of full paths that were removed. This currently wont affect directory structure. A switch change will address this if required. You will also see that `/l` is used for logging only. You can use that switch to test to see if the files you want are being removed. For actual production testing you would need to remove that.

```
/minage:N        Specifies the minimum file age (exclude files newer than N days or date).
/njh             Specifies that there is no job header.
/njs             Specifies that there is no job summary.
/l               Specifies that files are to be listed only (and not copied, deleted, or time stamped).
/mov             Moves files, and deletes them from the source after they are copied.
/ndl             Specifies that directory names are not to be logged.
/nc              Specifies that file classes are not to be logged.\
/np              Specifies that the progress of the copying operation (the number of files or directories copied so far) will not be displayed.
```

This will also perform faster if it is not spending time displaying data on the screen. That is why I specifically put `/np` in there.